Azure AI Search Azure Table as source
I am using a MySQL database to store article details, with Article Headline and BodyText as the main columns. There are millions of records in the article table, and search performance is becoming increasingly slower due to the use of the LIKE operator on text columns.
I am planning to switch to an Azure AI-based solution for better search performance. According to the documentation and the analysis of various data source options provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-azure-cognitive-search-solution/3-search-components, Azure Table Storage is one of the potential data sources.
Is Azure Table Storage capable of handling this volume of records effectively?

have you tried using azure sql database as source? give it a try

Migration to Azure sql is not feasible atm due to pricing constraints on the project. Looking for a economical workaround and i can see 2 options like blob storage and azure tables

then using blob is better one
